# Smarty template loop in multidimensional Array (3)

Tags: php, loops, templates, smarty, smarty3

I'm having some trouble displaying some of my values in a smarty template.
I've read many stackoverflow subjects but didn't get mine to work from the answers. i'm a smarty beginner but I need to use it for some work.

Here is my problem.

I have an array which gives:

```
Array (12)
0 => Array (7)
  0 => Array (2)
    total => "0"
    department_name => "その他"
  1 => Array (2)
    total => "0"
    department_name => "イベント"
  2 => Array (2)
    total => "0"
    department_name => "ウェブ"
  3 => Array (2)
    total => "0"
    department_name => "グラフィック"
```

and so on.
1 to 12 months, 1 to 7 department names,  and 2 properties (name and number).
The total = 0 is normal in my case, there are indeed values in the array later.

I want to display the "total" in each cell.
I tried this amongst many other variant with no luck

```
{FOREACH $date_fixed as $dates}
    <tr>
        <td scope="row">{$dates}</td>
        <td>
            <span>
                  <!-- {$balance_report.row_total_balance} -->
            </span>
        </td>
        {FOREACH $test as $ok}
            {FOREACH $ok as $i}
                <td>
                    <span>
                        {$i.total}
                    </span>
                </td>
            {/FOREACH}
        {/FOREACH}
    </tr>
{/FOREACH}
```

I don't really get why it doesn't work.
My table only has 0s as values. and is waaaaay too long.
I guess my problem is on the displaying of dates.

how can I have a nice table? How can I loop properly on a 3Dimensionnal array?

Let me know if I forgot some crucial information.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work the way I THINK I wanted.
Correct me if I am mistaken.

```
{FOREACH $date_fixed as $i => $dates}
<tr>
    <td scope="row">{$dates}</td>
    <td>
        <span>
              <!-- {$balance_report.row_total_balance} -->
        </span>
    </td>
    {FOREACH $test[$i] as $ok}
    <td>
       <span>
           {$ok.total}
       </span>
    </td>
    {/FOREACH}
</tr>
{/FOREACH}
```